# CRUD operation using jooq in spring boot + postman

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, postman, jooq

```
@RestController
public class BookController {

    
    @Autowired
    BookService bookService;
    
    @PostMapping("/saveBook")
    public void postBook(@RequestBody Book book) {
        
        this.bookService.insertBook(book);
    }
    
    
     @GetMapping("/allBooks")
     public Result<Record> getBooks(){
            return this.bookService.getBooks();
        }
}
```

I am trying to perform a crud operation using jooq+postgresql in spring boot, calling APIs from the postman. But it is not working. Please share some link and your ideas.

[I am sending the JSON object from postman but is not convert in the book object.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUehY.png)

Comment: What does insertBook do?

Comment: it is a function for storing book object data in the PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Please show the code. Also explain what you mean by "is not working"